# Jquery function should be executed when the checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

My JavaScript code is like this and for this function should run only when the check box is checked on and this should not run when the check box is checked out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function zoom() {
    $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
            effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
            effectDuration: 450,
            keyNav: true,
            mouseNav: true,
            coeffZoom: 2.5,
            speedOpenLightBox: 100,
            legendPadding: 5,
            legendOpacity: 0.8
        });

    });
```

Comment: What checkbox? What's your question?

Comment: What does this exactly do is when we click on an image the image will zoom out and again when we click the image will zoom in and my requirement is zoom out and zoom in should work only when the check box button is checked...

Answer (score 1):

say you have the checkbox with `id="chkboxID"` on document ready you can use the `.is` method, but this will only be checked on page load

```
    $(function(){

    if($("#chkboxID").is(":checked")){
    $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
                effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
                effectDuration: 450,
                keyNav: true,
                mouseNav: true,
                coeffZoom: 2.5,
                speedOpenLightBox: 100,
                legendPadding: 5,
                legendOpacity: 0.8
            });    
    }    
  });
```

**update:**

> the updated code will attach the change event handler to every
>   checkbox on the page if you want to listen to the changes of the
>   specific check box change the selector accordingly

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked"))
 {
   $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
                    effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
                    effectDuration: 450,
                    keyNav: true,
                    mouseNav: true,
                    coeffZoom: 2.5,
                    speedOpenLightBox: 100,
                    legendPadding: 5,
                    legendOpacity: 0.8
                });
 }
});
```

Comment: I am using this code in a visual web part in visual studio for a share point site  but the result is not seen if i check or uncheck the checkbox the jquery is running...

Answer (score 1):

```
function zoom() {
    $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
        effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
        effectDuration: 450,
        keyNav: true,
        mouseNav: true,
        coeffZoom: 2.5,
        speedOpenLightBox: 100,
        legendPadding: 5,
        legendOpacity: 0.8
    });
}

$(function () {
    $( < your checkbox selector > ).change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            zoom();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: When i use this condition and check or uncheck the checkbox the image is opening in a new window...

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbox_value = 1; //Its checked on 

if(checkbox_value){

    $(document).ready(function zoom() {
    $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
            effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
            effectDuration: 450,
            keyNav: true,
            mouseNav: true,
            coeffZoom: 2.5,
            speedOpenLightBox: 100,
            legendPadding: 5,
            legendOpacity: 0.8
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="mycheck" type="checkbox"/>​
```

js:

```
 $(".mycheck").change(function(){
        if(this.checked){ zoom(); }

    })​

    function zoom() {
    $('.ThumbaGallery').Thumba({
            effectThumba: 'easeOutBack',
            effectDuration: 450,
            keyNav: true,
            mouseNav: true,
            coeffZoom: 2.5,
            speedOpenLightBox: 100,
            legendPadding: 5,
            legendOpacity: 0.8
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you want to define the function inside the `if` statement, you want to call it.